# BOOTSTRAP Carousel isn't sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

BOOTSTRAP Carousel isn't sliding at all 
I've been trying to make this carousel work but it didn't want to slide stays always on the active slide and buttons doest work as well i've checked all the links all the files in JS and css everysingle one works but i can't tell why the carousel isn't sliding just stays on the active one

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="carousel-staffpick" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-staffpick" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-staffpick" data-slide-to="1"
                        class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-staffpick" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <!-- item 01 -->
                    <div class="item  text-center">
                        <img src="{% static 'img/client-01.jpg' %}" alt="staffpick" class="center-block">
                        <div class="staffpick-caption">
                            <h2>Ryad Mahrer</h2>
                            <h4>
                                <span> FootBall Player </span>Licter City
                            </h4>
                            <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                                do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                                laboris nisi ut aliquip.”</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- item 02 -->
                    <div class="item active text-center">
                        <img src="{% static 'img/client-02.jpg' %}" alt="client-02" class="center-block">
                        <div class="staffpick-caption">
                            <h2>zlatan ibrahimovic</h2>
                            <h4>
                                <span> FootBall PLayer </span>Man Unt
                            </h4>
                            <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                                do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                                laboris nisi ut aliquip.”</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- item 03 -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <img src="{% static 'img/client-03.jpg' %}" alt="staffpick" class="center-block">
                        <div class="staffpick-caption">
                            <h2>Jamie Vardy</h2>
                            <h4>
                                <span> FootBall PLayer </span>Licter City
                            </h4>
                            <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                                do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                                laboris nisi ut aliquip.”</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> 
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 2000
        })
      });    
    </script>
```

Edit : I've tried the slider works when i try it online but it won't work on my localhost

Comment: Where is `bootstrap.js`? Have you attached it?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes i've attached bootstrap.js .. and i'm getting no errror just it wont slide

Comment: you have your bootstrap.js called before jquery, bootstrap requires jquery. Just change the order so jquery is first.

Comment: thanks that solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had bootstrap.js called before jquery, bootstrap requires jquery.
by changing the order so jquery is first the problem solved 
thanks to [Bosc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3365721/bosc)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have forgotten to add "bootstrap.js"

for your reference I have created codepen please have a look

http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/gLorga

```
 [1]: http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/gLorga
```